# Typescript "Property does not exists on type Element"

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm starting my journey with Typescript. So I have `video` tag in my Html and in `.ts` file these lines:

```
...
class KomakhaPlayer {
  private container = ...;
  private video: Element = this.container.getElementsByClassName( 'video' )[ 0 ];
  private controls = ...;

  constructor(){
    this.video.controls = false; // ts error
    ...
  }
}
...
```

As you can see `this.video` has **Element** type, but below `this.video.controls` throws me a Typescript error **Property 'controls' does not exists on type 'Element'**.

Temporary I changed `Element` type to `any`, but I want to **know** how properly solve this error and handle similar in future. Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**
So the right approach is defining like this:

```
private video: HTMLVideoElement = <HTMLVideoElement>this.container.getElementsByClassName( 'video' )[ 0 ];
```

Explanation by **@deceze** below in comments

Comment: use `this. controls` no? instead of `this.video.controls`

Comment: Is `Element` a custom class or is it part of a library you're using

Comment: @Smit, no ``this.video.controls``, **controls** is a property of video tag

Comment: `private video: Element = this.container.getElementsByClassName( 'video' )[ 0 ];`  avoid the assignment outside methods. Instead put it inside the constructor.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David, that is from Typescropt definitions

Comment: `Element` indeed does not have a property `controls`. `HTMLVideoElement` might.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Element` is a very generic root object which indeed does not have a `controls` attribute. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element. What you're looking for is an [`HTMLVideoElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement), which inherits from [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), which has a [`controls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controls) attribute.

Typescript is entirely correct: you told it you're working with an `Element`, and Typescript warns you that an `Element` is not known to have `controls`.

Comment: thanks, I've got it work like this: ``private video: HTMLVideoElement = <HTMLVideoElement>this.container.getElementsByClassName( 'video' )[ 0 ];``. But one thing I don't understand why I need to cast ``<HTMLVideoElement>``? Typescript can't figure that this is video type?

Comment: No it cannot. What element exactly will be returned by `getElementsByClassName('video')` is only known at runtime, not at compile time. At compile time the best Typescript can infer is that it's going to be some sort of `Element`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type like this:

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video') as HTMLVideoElement | null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your statement (emphasis mine)

> So I have ***video tag*** in my Html and in .ts file these lines:

```
class KomakhaPlayer {
  private video: Element = this.container.getElementsByClassName('video')[0];    
  constructor(){
    this.video.controls = false; // ts error
  }
}
```

You have made two critical errors.

First or foremost, to get the correct runtime behavior you need to elements by their ***tag name***. That is you use `document.getElementsByTagName` not `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Resolving this results in

```
class KomakhaPlayer {
  private video: Element = this.container.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];    
  constructor(){
    this.video.controls = false; // ts error
  }
}
```

And still, there is an error.

This is because of a critical misunderstanding. You've overspecified the types in your program, preventing the language from performing its highly sophisticated type inference. One you remove the `: Element` type annotation from the `video` field, you code works type checks because the compiler has *more* type information *not* less. Say less and get more.

```
class KomakhaPlayer {
  private video = this.container.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];    
  constructor(){
    this.video.controls = false;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=52#code/CYewxgrgtgpgdgFwHQHMYIKIBsa0QZwCEBPAFQEMUA5c2ACgHIA3AS2BhAYEoBtABgC6SMCEQAnEFnwBuIA)

TypeScript is about having type information not type writing type annotations.
Write type annotations where the compiler does not know what the types are or when you want to formalize an API, not when you are initializing a field.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in my code.

```
const value = 'hello world';

const el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('id_of_element') as HTMLElement;
el.innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and it is very poor code. You have a misleading annotation and completely redundant annotation that is only allowed by TS because of an unsafe type assertion. `document.getElementById('id_of_element')` returns `HTMLElement | null`. You don't need an annotation or an `as HTMLElement` assertion. `document.getElementById('id_of_element')?.innerHTML = value` _or_ `document.getElementById('id_of_element')!.innerHTML = value;` depending on whether you want your app to crash if there element with that id.