# BrowserStack, WDIO, Cucumber, TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io, browserstack

I'm trying to get up with my automation tests using Cucumber, typescript, webdriverio and browserstack.

It seems like there is no up to date setup guide for this kind of stack and I encountered some problem with the TS. When I set up all the configs and features for the tests I keep getting TS error `Error:(7, 54) TS2339: Property 'element' does not exist on type 'BrowserObject'.`

I believe there is some problem with the TS config or so.

Is anyone able to point me what's wrong?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./tsrc",
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "chai",
      "@wdio/sync",
      "webdriverio",
      "cucumber"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./tests/tsrc"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

wdio.conf.js

```
exports.config = {

  //
  // =================
  // Service Providers
  // =================
  // WebdriverIO supports Sauce Labs, Browserstack, and Testing Bot (other cloud providers
  // should work too though). These services define specific user and key (or access key)
  // values you need to put in here in order to connect to these services.
  //
  user: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USER_NAME,
  key: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_KEY,


  //
  // ==================
  // Specify Test Files
  // ==================
  // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
  // from which `wdio` was called. Notice that, if you are calling `wdio` from an
  // NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) then the current working
  // directory is where your package.json resides, so `wdio` will be called from there.
  //
  specs: [
    './tests/features/*.feature'
  ],
  // Patterns to exclude.
  exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
  ],
  //
  // ============
  // Capabilities
  // ============
  // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
  // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
  // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
  // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
  //
  // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
  // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
  // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
  // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
  // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
  // from the same test should run tests.
  //
  maxInstances: 1,
  //
  // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
  // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
  // https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator
  //
  capabilities: [{
    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 1,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }],
  //
  // ===================
  // Test Configurations
  // ===================
  // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
  //
  // By default WebdriverIO commands are executed in a synchronous way using
  // the wdio-sync package. If you still want to run your tests in an async way
  // e.g. using promises you can set the sync option to false.
  sync: true,
  //
  // Level of logging verbosity: silent | verbose | command | data | result | error
  logLevel: 'verbose',
  //
  // Enables colors for log output.
  coloredLogs: true,
  //
  // Warns when a deprecated command is used
  deprecationWarnings: true,
  //
  // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
  // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
  bail: 0,
  //
  // Saves a screenshot to a given path if a command fails.
  screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
  //
  // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
  // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
  // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
  // gets prepended directly.
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  //
  // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  //
  // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
  // if Selenium Grid doesn't send response
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  //
  // Default request retries count
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  //
  // Initialize the browser instance with a WebdriverIO plugin. The object should have the
  // plugin name as key and the desired plugin options as properties. Make sure you have
  // the plugin installed before running any tests. The following plugins are currently
  // available:
  // WebdriverCSS: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdrivercss
  // WebdriverRTC: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverrtc
  // Browserevent: https://github.com/webdriverio/browserevent
  // plugins: {
  //     webdrivercss: {
  //         screenshotRoot: 'my-shots',
  //         failedComparisonsRoot: 'diffs',
  //         misMatchTolerance: 0.05,
  //         screenWidth: [320,480,640,1024]
  //     },
  //     webdriverrtc: {},
  //     browserevent: {}
  // },
  //
  // Test runner services
  // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
  // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
  // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
  services: ['browserstack'],
  //
  // Framework you want to run your specs with.
  // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
  // see also: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/frameworks.html
  //
  // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
  // before running any tests.
  framework: 'cucumber',
  //
  // Test reporter for stdout.
  // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
  // see also: http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/dot.html
  reporters: ['spec', 'junit'],
  //
  // If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions.
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./tests/steps/*.ts'],        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
    backtrace: false,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    compiler: ['ts:ts-node/register'],       // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    failFast: false,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    colors: true,       // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
    snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    source: true,       // <boolean> hide source uris
    profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
    strict: false,      // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    tags: [],           // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    timeout: 20000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
  },

  //
  // =====
  // Hooks
  // =====
  // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
  // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
  // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
  // resolved to continue.
  /**
   * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
   * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   */
  onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    console.log('<<< BROWSER TESTS STARTED >>>');
  },
  /**
   * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
   * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
   * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
   */
  // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
  // },
  /**
   * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
   * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
   */
  before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    require('ts-node').register({ files: true });
  },
  /**
   * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
   * @param {String} commandName hook command name
   * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
   */
  // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
  // },

  /**
   * Runs before a Cucumber feature
   * @param {Object} feature feature details
   */
  // beforeFeature: function (feature) {
  // },
  /**
   * Runs before a Cucumber scenario
   * @param {Object} scenario scenario details
   */
  // beforeScenario: function (scenario) {
  // },
  /**
   * Runs before a Cucumber step
   * @param {Object} step step details
   */
  // beforeStep: function (step) {
  // },
  /**
   * Runs after a Cucumber step
   * @param {Object} stepResult step result
   */
  // afterStep: function (stepResult) {
  // },
  /**
   * Runs after a Cucumber scenario
   * @param {Object} scenario scenario details
   */
  // afterScenario: function (scenario) {
  // },
  /**
   * Runs after a Cucumber feature
   * @param {Object} feature feature details
   */
  // afterFeature: function (feature) {
  // },

  /**
   * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
   * @param {String} commandName hook command name
   * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
   * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
   * @param {Object} error error object if any
   */
  // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
  // },
  /**
   * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
   * the test.
   * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
   */
  // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
  // },
  /**
   * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
   * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
   */
  // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
  // },
  /**
   * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit.
   * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
   * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   */
  onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities) {
    console.log('<<< BROWSER TESTING FINISHED >>>');
  }
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript "Property does not exists on type Element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837520/typescript-property-does-not-exists-on-type-element)

Answer (score 0):

try adding 'wdio-cucumber-framework' to your types inside the tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty late answer, but it looks like the problem is with the types that you are specifying. According to [webdriver.io documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html), you should have either webdriverio or @wdio/sync in your types but not both.

"For sync mode (@wdio/sync), webdriverio types must be replaced with @wdio/sync.

Please avoid importing webdriverio or @wdio/sync explicitly. WebdriverIO and WebDriver types are accessible from anywhere once added to types in tsconfig.json."